# Form input validations using pure CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to apply CSS classes based on HTML element's property (not based on element's attribute) without using JavaScript?

For example, consider below input element:

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" class="form-field__input" name="txtName" value="">
```

When user interacts with above element and enters some text, its "value" property gets updated; but "value" attribute remains empty. By any means can we access element's property inside CSS ? I know it is possible to update "value" attribute using JavaScript, and then using attribute selectors update the styles; but is there any way to achieve this using CSS selectors only ?

To clarify, I am not concerned about whether the input is valid or not, I just want to check availability of content, and if the content is present then "any-css-rule-1" should get applied, otherwise "any-css-rule-2".

Comment: What are you trying to match at user input? Which `css` rules should be applied at which conditions?

Comment: You get a lot of free validation with HTML5 inputs.  Have you tried those to see if they meet your needs?

Comment: I am trying to add two different classes based on presence of content inside input box without using any JS. It seems like it is not possible to do this.

Comment: @Sameer It is not possible to add `.className` to an element at `html` `document` at `css` file or using `CSSOM`. You can use `html` attributes to provide notification to user as to expected input; check user input against a regular expression; render `css` content based on user input matching or not matching regular expression pattern. A `<form>` element can also be prevented from being submitted if user input does not match regular expression at `pattern` attribute of `form` element and `required` attribute is set, without using `javascript`.

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry for the word "add", what I meant was to match any 2 different CSS rules. Also, I am not concerned about whether the input is valid or not, I just want to check availability of content, and if the content is present then "any-css-rule-1" should get applied, and if not then "any-css-rule-2".

Comment: You would need to use `:valid`, `:invalid` pseudo selectors at `css` and `pattern` attribute and `required` attribute at `html`. Else, no, the functionality that you are trying to implement is not currently possible using `css` alone. `css` `[att=value]`, `[att*=value]` and other `css`  attribute  selectors matches attribute name and value at `html`, not current user input at the form field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pattern`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) and `required` attributes at `html`; `:valid`, `:invalid` pseudo classes at `css` to match specific user input.

```css
:valid + [for="txtName"]:after {
  content: "valid input";
  color: green;
}

:invalid + [for="txtName"]:after {
  content: "invalid input";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- match the regex pattern (minimum 8 chars) -->
<input type="text" 
       id="txtName" 
       class="form-field__input" 
       name="txtName" 
       value="" 
       pattern=".{8,}" 
       required />
<label for="txtName"></label>
```

Comment: A hint to user as to expected valid input can be provided at `title` and `placeholder` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with combination of HTML5 and CSS3 features. Here is my sample code:

**HTML:**

```
<form  action="#" class="contact-us-form" onsubmit="submitClick()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last name">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.contact-us-form {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
  flex-direction: column;

  .text-field {
    margin: 0.5em;
  }
  .button-submit {
    margin: 1em;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
  }

  input[type="text"],
  input[type="email"] {
    margin: 0.5em;
    height: 2em;
    min-width: 125px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: border-color 0.5s ease-out;

    &:optional {
      border-left-color: #999;
    }
    &:required {
      border-left-color: red;
    }
    &:invalid {
      border-left-color: salmon;
    }
  }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function submitClick() {
 alert("Your data has been saved");
}
```

Here is the link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqLf8hcs/1/)